# Shell script to identify missing values in a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am looking for a method (shell script) which will help me identify a missing value (in a column) from a file which is in following format.

> Head1|Head2           |Head3   |Head4        |Head5|Head6                     |Head7 |Head8|Head9 |Head10|Head11 |Head12|Head13|
>
> 15   |DRE-NCL             |            |            |      |                              |      |2    |USD |       |        |     |2  |
>
> 15   |HTBCL               |            |            |      |                              |      |2    |USD |       |        |     |2  |

Questions:

1. How to read a file line by line?
2. How to dissect a line and store in array?
3. Any other Ideas to find empty cells OR missing values?

Comment: you'll need to give a better specification. Do you care that many of those fields have missing values, or just 1 or 2 fields. THEN what sort of output will make it easiest to "fix" (whatever your definition of that is) the problem. Please edit the question above and learn to use the `code` highlighting tool `{}` near the top left of the edit box. Your `Qs` are easily answered once we know the scope and your required output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lineno=0
while IFS='|' read -ra fields; do
    ((lineno++))
    for idx in "${!fields[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${fields[idx]%% } == "" ]]; then
            echo "line number $lineno has at least one empty field"
            break
        fi
    done
done < filename
```

`"${!fields[@]}"` gives you the *indices* of the array, not the elements.

`${fields[idx]%% }` is a parameter expansion that takes the value and removes all trailing spaces. It's not strictly required to use double quotes here because it's inside bash's `[[ ... ]]`

From the bash manual, read:

- [Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays)
- [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Hi glenn, Thanks for your answer. I need this snippet. Could you also care to explain working of following:

a. "${!fields[@]}" --> In this case Why is '!' (not) used in array?
b. [[ ${fields[idx]%% } --> how is this working?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use `cut` command. like:

```
cut -d'|' -f2 filename
```

this print 2nd field (using | as delimiter) of all line. for your file output is :

```
Head2
DRE-NCL
HTBCL
```

now you can use this hint to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
lineno=0
# read the file line-by-line, 
# splitting each line (using pipe separator) into the "fields" array
while IFS='|' read -ra fields; do
    ((lineno++))
    for idx in "${!fields[@]}"; do
        # trim trailing spaces and compare to the empty string.
        if [[ ${fields[idx]%% } == "" ]]; then
            echo "line number $lineno has at least one empty field"
            break
        fi
    done
done < filename
```